# Android ffmpeg command shows java.io.IOException: Error running exec()

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exec

I would like to use `ffmpeg` binary executable in my Android project.for this purpose I have used pre built ffmpeg Android binary from this(https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android/releases/download/v0.3.3/prebuilt-binaries.zip) link.

As per procedure I have to place the `executable` file into `/data/data/com.example.rampedsample` directory, here `com.example.rampedsample` is my project packageName.I couldn't find this location in my device as it is un rooted.So I pasted that executable into `Android emulator`'s `com.example.rampedsample` directory using `DDMS` perspective.

In my Activity used the below code

```
 try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.example.rampedsample/ffmpeg "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Movies/ramp_video.mp4"
                    +" -map 0:v -codec copy "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Movies/ramp_video2.mp4");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**AndroidManifest permission**

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"         
    />
```

**error**

```
04-13 16:59:55.314: W/System.err(11387): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.example.rampedsample/ffmpeg, /mnt/sdcard/Movies/ramp_video.mp4, -map, 0:v, -codec, copy, /mnt/sdcard/Movies/ramp_video2.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
04-13 16:59:55.314: W/System.err(11387):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at com.example.rampedsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-13 16:59:55.355: W/System.err(11387):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
```

Comment: You may not have set the file executable.  In actual operation on a secured device, your program will probably have to copy out the program itself and set it executable.  The run-as tool can be useful in testing.  This is not something you want to be doing without taking time to really understand what is going on.

Comment: You meant the downloaded `ffmpeg` is not executable

Answer (score 0):

Please add READ and WRITE storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also see this command and use it

```
"-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -s hd720 " + newFile.getPath()

old path - /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/input.mp4
new path - storage/emulated/0/DCIM/output.mp4
```